# Assessing int data from pandas.Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
data = pandas.read_csv("weather_data.csv")
print(type(data['temp'][1]))
```

When I tried to print out the type of the integer data accessed from a `panda.Series`, it shows `<class 'numpy.int64'>`, does it mean `numpy` is primarily embedded in `pandas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [dependency](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#dependencies), it says

> NumPy - Adds support for large, multi-dimensional arrays, matrices and high-level mathematical functions to operate on these arrays

So yes, `numpy` is internally imported in `pandas` (so the `to_numpy` function works).

However, you should still `import numpy` when you want to directly use `numpy`'s functions.